# Can one experimentally confirm whether the effective attractive interaction is retarded and its relation with superconductivity?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, superconductivity, phonons, strong-correlated

It's widely believed that in convential  BCS superconductors, only after taking the retardation effect into consideration the weak attractive interaction mediated by phonons can overwhelm the strong Coulomb interaction, which can be modeled by Eliashberg theory. However, though experimental facts like the isotope effect indicate the phonons play a role, and we know from the theoretic side that it brings an attractive interaction that is retarded, and we also need such attractive interaction with retardation to account for experiments observed superconductivity, I also wonder if there will be direct evidence to show the retarded nature of the effective attractive interaction. A related thing is that some unconventional superconductivity, e.g.  [superconductivity in fullerene](https://www.science.org/doi/epdf/10.1126/science.1071122) , are supposed to originate from the strong correlation effect of the interplay between small non-retarded attractive interaction (e.g. negative Hund's coupling) and strong Hubbard repulsion.

So, I wonder if there will be some experiments to tell us that, indeed, we can find that in conventional BCS superconductors, there is retarded effective attraction, while in this type of superconductor, there is not. Furthermore, can one experimentally confirm the relation of the retardation effect and the superconductivity?